How to send the exported CSV file from the PrimeVue Table Component to my backend instead of downloading it locally
I'm using PrimeVue Table Component and want to export a CSV file out of it. With this function it works perfectly fine.
Now I don't want it to download in my browser but to send it to my rest api backend. I cannot find any parameters allowing me to do that.
Is there a way to send this CSV file directly to the backend?
Thx in advance.

You are not using PrimeFaces

exportCSV function does not have any support for not downloading the csv, it will always download the csv. But on IE it will not download the CSV and instead will open the CSV in a window.

which means I am doomed right?

why does the backend need to receive the data as CSV?  can't you send the raw table data with API request?  Maybe you can find backend library to convert to CSV after it receives the data.
